# Adding 1 subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, dns, subdomain

Alright, so unlike other solutions I only want one subdomain to appear to be added.

Say I wanted `example.com/folder/page.php` to be displayed as `foo.example.com/folder/page.php`, how would I go about doing this?

The `foo` will never change, and it only needs to be for one page.

Various other sites have been unable to provide an answer, thanks in advance.

Edit: Oh, and I also have full DNS records to the domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can not add a subdomain via the `.htaccess` file.

You need to modify the vHost configuration and/or add one more vHost.

Have a look at the documentation of your webserver to see how to do this.

**EDIT:**
There is a logical reason behind this (I don't know all webservers and their features, so correct me if I say something wrong):

Let's look at a typical HTTP request (sent by the client):

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
```

So, we have the following information in this request:

- the *uri*: `index.php`
- the protocol version we understand: `HTTP/1.1`
- the Host (*vhost*) we want the *uri* from

On such a request, the webserver does a few lookups:

1. `Host`: first the server needs to know in which directory he should look, this is part of the *vHost* configuration
2. the *uri* you are looking for

As the `.htaccess` file belongs to a vHost (eg. `a.example.org`), we are dependent on the vHost having already been decided.

Comment: Is there not some sort of solution of setting up that subdomain, and using the .htaccess on it to display the content from the base url (no subdomain)?

Comment: @Jake i will edit my comment to provide more information WHY it is not possible

Comment: But surely if it's possible to add wildcard subdomains, by editing DNS records, it is much easier to just add one? For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php ?

Comment: @Jake if you look at the top answer: This is done via server alias. Here you need to modify the virtual host config too. And you need to script the "subdomains" in php, there is still no way to do this via .htaccess

Comment: Alright, so is there NO way to get the content from domain.com/folder/page to display at foo.domain.com/folder/page, short of actually moving it?

Comment: @Jake: of course you could configure a vhost, overlaping whith the current, but you question was not if it is possible to display the image also on a subdomain. You asked who you could do this via .htaccess, and there is no way!

Comment: @Jake Where do you host your site? Check their Control Panel -- any decent CP will allow you to add subdomains to your domain hosting and point it to any folder on your site. In other words -- use your hoster's Control Panel to configure subdomain .. and the rest (URL rewrite) can be done in .htaccess (if mod_rewrite is available).